# Swift: Creating a randomized scrolling scene similar to Alto's Adventure

Tags: ios, swift, random, sprite-kit

How do the programmers of this game create a randomized game scene where the mountain that I am snowboarding down recreates itself every time. I imagine that they have incorporated `GKPerlinNoiseSource` to create a randomization effect where the regenerated mountain terrain to the right is affected by what is to the left, that way there are no sudden spikes, like a normal random curve. But I am unsure how you would go from a GKNoise or a GKNoiseMap to a one-dimensional regenerating terrain. This same thing would go for any game where the terrain regenerates itself in a 1-dimensional sequence.

Would you do something different than use a noise source, and what would you recommend? One thing I realize in this game is that many small areas are scenes that are played over in a random order.

Comment: do you have a video of this I can look at?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk5JupHelAg
Quick google search

Comment: It's a work of art that game.

Comment: this game looks like it was made with unity or cocos or a custom openGL engine.

Nobody knows how to use GameplayKit :) but it looks like that + parallaxing would get somewhere similar effect you are looking for